# How to count maximum value for given time period in R?

Tags: r, max

I got the data from MySQL and I'm trying to visualize it and uncover some answers. **Using R for the statistic.**

The final product is % discount for reach price change (=row).

Here is an example of my dataset.

```
     itemId pricehis           timestamp
1  69295477     1290 2022-04-12 04:42:53
2  69295624     1145 2022-04-12 04:42:53
3  69296136     3609 2022-04-12 04:42:54
4  69296607      855 2022-04-12 04:42:53
5  69295291     1000 2022-04-12 04:42:50
6  69295475     4188 2022-04-12 04:42:52
7  69295614     1145 2022-04-12 04:42:51
8  69295622     1290 2022-04-12 04:42:50
9  69295692     3609 2022-04-12 04:42:49
10 69295917     1725 2022-04-12 04:42:48
11 69296090     2449 2022-04-12 04:42:53
12 69296653     1145 2022-04-12 04:42:51
13 69296657     5638 2022-04-12 04:42:48
14 69296661     1725 2022-04-12 04:42:51
15 69296696      710 2022-04-12 04:42:51
```

I've been stuck at one part of the calculation - maximum value for each productId in 6 months.

In the dataset there are rows for specific productId with different pricehis values and different timestamps. I need to find the max value for a given row no older than 6 months.

The formula for calculating the desired discount is:

`Discount grouped by itemId =  1 - pricehis / max(pricehis in the last 6 months)`

At this moment I'm unable to solve the second part - pricehis in the last 6 months.
**- I need a new column with maximum 'pricehis' in the last 6 months for the itemId.** Also could be known as interval maximum.

I can group it by the itemId, but I can't figure out how to add the condition on 6 months max.

Any tips on how to get this?

Comment: Not sure of your level and which R approach you are looking at (base, tidyverse, etc). You need to  first aggregate by product IDs, then you need to look for entries <= 6 months, then you need to find the max of those entries. In base R look at aggregate(). In tidyverse look at various group_by = options. Both of these options and others (e.g. in purrr) allow you to pass a function like max() into each subgroup.

Comment: It will be easier to test and demonstrate potential solutions if you can suggest some example data that includes a wider range of values that cover a span of longer than 6mo, instead of <1 minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like `slider::slide_index_dbl` for this sort of thing. Here's some fake data chosen to demonstrate the 6mo window:

```
data.frame(itemId = rep(1:2, each = 6),
           price = floor(100*cos(0:11)^2),
           timestamp = as.Date("2000-01-01") + 50*(0:11)) -> df
```

We can start with `df`, group it by itemId, and then calula and then apply the window function. (Note that `slider` requires the data to be sorted by date within each group.)

```
library(dplyr).  
library(lubridate) # for `%m-%`, to get sliding months (harder than it sounds!)
df %>%     
  group_by(itemId) %>%
  mutate(max_6mo = slider::slide_index_dbl(.x = price,     # based on price...
                                           .i = timestamp, # and timestamp...
                                           .f = max,       # what's the max...
                                           .before = ~.x %m-% months(6))) %>% # over the last 6mo
  mutate(discount = 1 - price / max_6mo) %>%               # use that to calc discount
  ungroup()
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 12 × 5
   itemId price timestamp  max_6mo discount
    <int> <dbl> <date>       <dbl>    <dbl>
 1      1   100 2000-01-01     100   0     
 2      1    29 2000-02-20     100   0.71  
 3      1    17 2000-04-10     100   0.83  
 4      1    98 2000-05-30     100   0.0200
 5      1    42 2000-07-19      98   0.571    # new max since >6mo since 100
 6      1     8 2000-09-07      98   0.918 
 7      2    92 2000-10-27      92   0     
 8      2    56 2000-12-16      92   0.391 
 9      2     2 2001-02-04      92   0.978 
10      2    83 2001-03-26      92   0.0978
11      2    70 2001-05-15      83   0.157    # new max since >6mo since 92
12      2     0 2001-07-04      83   1
```

Comment: Hello Jon, thank you very much for your answer. It seems to be working very well! Thank you for sharing your knowledge.

However, I need some time to understand what is going on in the code.